# Collection with both Set and List interface

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

Here's something I wrote a while ago.  I needed a collection that was ordered, but also guaranteed duplicates did not occur.  So I made a class with both Set and List interfaces.  It seems to work well.

I'm interested if there are better ways of doing this, maybe in the standard API or some library.  I'd also be interested in general comments, if anyone cares to offer them.

This is a fairly simple implementation, designed to meet my immediate needs.  There's probably lots of ways it could be made more fancy.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Unholy spawn of set and list!
 * 
 * <p>@code HashSetList} is similar to {@code LinkedHashSet}.  Objects
 * inserted can be retrieved in a predicable order.  Unlike
 * {@code LinkedHashSet}, this class implements more of the {@code List}
 * API, including a reverse iterator and a subList() method.
 * </p>
 * 
 * <p><b>Very lightly tested!</b>  Caveat emptor.</p>
 * 
 * @author Brenden Towey
 * @param <T> The type parameter of the {@code HashSetList}.
 */
public class HashSetList<T> implements Set<T>, List<T>
{
   private final HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<>();
   private final ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public boolean containsAll(
           Collection<?> c )
   {
      return set.containsAll( c );
   }

   @Override
   public int size()
   {
      return list.size();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return list.isEmpty();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean contains( Object o )
   {
      return set.contains( o );
   }

   @Override
   public int indexOf( Object o )
   {
      return list.indexOf( o );
   }

   @Override
   public int lastIndexOf( Object o )
   {
      return list.lastIndexOf( o );
   }

//   @Override
//   public Object clone()
//   {
//      try {
//         HashSetList copy = (HashSetList) super.clone();
//         return copy;
//      } catch( CloneNotSupportedException ex ) {
//         throw new AssertionError( "This should NOT happen.", ex );
//      }
//   }

   @Override
   public Object[] toArray()
   {
      return list.toArray();
   }

   @Override
   public <T> T[] toArray( T[] a )
   {
      return list.toArray( a );
   }

   @Override
   public T get( int index )
   {
      return list.get( index );
   }

   /**
    * Throws {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.
    * 
    * @param index
    * @param element 
    */
   @Override
   public T set( int index, T element )
   {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
//      return list.set( index, element );
   }

   @Override
   public boolean add( T e )
   {
      if( set.add( e ) ) {
         return list.add( e ); // always returns true
      }
      return false;
   }

   /**
    * Throws {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.
    * 
    * @param index
    * @param element 
    */
   @Override
   public void add( int index, T element )
   {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
//      list.add( index, element );
   }

   /**
    * Throws {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.
    * 
    * @param index
    */
   @Override
   public T remove( int index )
   {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
//      return list.remove( index );
   }

   @Override
   public boolean remove( Object o )
   {
      if( set.remove( o ) )
         return list.remove( o );
      else
         return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void clear()
   {
      set.clear();
      list.clear();
   }

   /**
    * Adds all elements in the {@code Collection c} to this
    * {@code HashSetList}.  This method is implemented very simply
    * and likely to be quite slow.  Caveat emptor.
    * 
    * @param c {@code Collection} of elements to remove.
    * @return @{code true} if changed.
    */
   @Override
   public boolean addAll(
           Collection<? extends T> c )
   {
      boolean change = false;
      for( T x : c )
         change |= this.add( x );
      return change;
   }

   /**
    * Throws {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.
    * 
    * @param index
    * @param element 
    */
   @Override
   public boolean addAll( int index,
           Collection<? extends T> c )
   {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
//      return list.addAll( index, c );
   }

   /**
    * Removes all elements in the {@code Collection c} from this
    * {@code HashSetList}.  This method is implemented very simply
    * and likely to be quite slow.  Caveat emptor.
    * 
    * @param c {@code Collection} of elements to remove.
    * @return @{code true} if changed.
    */
   @Override
   public boolean removeAll(
           Collection<?> c )
   {
      boolean change = false;
      for( Object o : c )
         change |= this.remove( o );
      return change;
   }

   /**
    * Retains all elements in the {@code Collection c} which also in this
    * {@code HashSetList}.  (In other words it computes the intersection
    * of {@code c} and this {@code HashSetList}.
    * This method is implemented very simply
    * and likely to be quite slow.  Caveat emptor.
    * 
    * @param c {@code Collection} of elements to remove.
    * @return @{code true} if changed.
    */
   @Override
   public boolean retainAll(
           Collection<?> c )
   {
      boolean change = set.retainAll( c );
      change |= list.retainAll( c );
      return change;
   }

   @Override
   public ListIterator<T> listIterator( int index )
   {
      return list.listIterator( index );
   }

   @Override
   public ListIterator<T> listIterator()
   {
      return list.listIterator();
   }

   @Override
   public Iterator<T> iterator()
   {
      return list.iterator();
   }

   @Override
   public List<T> subList( int fromIndex, int toIndex )
   {
      return list.subList( fromIndex, toIndex );
   }

}
```

Comment: How many elements do you expect to keep in this kind of list?

Comment: Do you want "random access", such as `list.get(500)` or do you need this primarily for iteration or checking `.contains`? What exactly is the use-case here? Knowing that will make it easier to suggest exactly what you need.

Comment: I need random access because it implements a bi-directional cursor.  I use this class to implement the results of a search -- after finding a list of documents with search words, I intersect the list of documents together to find documents which contain the most words in common.  Then I store the results in this `HashSetList`.  The List part lets me go forwards and back in the results, and the Set part ensures I don't show the same document twice.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I gotta take back the comment I made earlier: In reply to `"How many elements do you expect to keep in this list?"` reviewing my code, this `HashSetList` is part of the cursor results only, and not the actual index.  So it could store as many documents (results) as the index holds, but that doesn't seem likely.  It holds as many results initially as the first intersection of documents that produces a result; i.e. the first set of documents which has some of the search words in common.

Comment: What you might be needing is perhaps a `LinkedList` and a `HashSet` ? The `LinkedList` provides easy forward and backward iteration, while the Set makes sure that it has not been added already. If forward and backward iteration is all you need, use a `ListIterator` and not repeatedly call the `get` method.

Comment: This comment I don't understand.  `List` provides a reverse iterator (`ListIterator` can go forwards and backwards), why do I need to specialize to `LinkedList` to get that?  The code above is already working correctly, what benefit would I gain from making modifications to it? OK, I see some issues with `ListIterator` in my code, I think I have some bug fixing.  Perhaps that's what you saw there.

Comment: It was just a hunch that `LinkedList` might be better, but of course it depends. For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: OK.  Given the memory requirements (the list may be very large) I think an internal `ArrayList` is best.  I don't do any insertions in the middle of a list (that's done during the parsing/indexing phase) so I don't need that capability either.

Answer (score 10):

There is a whole bunch of `throws UnsupportedOperationException` in your code. More specifically, everything that has to do with specific indexes seems to be unsupported.

All this makes me wonder: Should you really implement the `List` interface? In my opinion, you should not. Because essentially, those List-specific methods are not supported.

I think you should consider dropping that class entirely and use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) or [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), which I think should be sufficient for you.

I think what you are looking for is `LinkedHashSet` which is a `Set` that preserves the insertion order of elements that are added to it.

Comment: I think you're right about the `UnsupportedOperationException`.  I should figure out how to actually support them.  And I needed a `subList()` method specifically, which only List supports.  It seemed best to just say this clas is-a list (it is) and go from there.

Comment: The `List<T>` documentation expressly provides that it is legitimate for an implementation to provide a means of reading items by index without providing useful implementations of the `List<T>` members which would modify the list.

Comment: If there had been from the get-go a standard `ReadableList<T>` interface which was similar to `List<T>` but without the mutating members, that might be a better choice than `List<T>`, but as it is I think `List<T>` is the standard type for code to accept when it needs a sequence of items which can be read via index.

Comment: That is a good point, @supercat. I still think thought that `LinkedHashSet` should be sufficient.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: If it's necessary to pass the collection to a method which expects a `List<T>`, then it needs to implement that interface.  Even if the method only needed members that are in `LinkedHashSet<T>`, Java isn't duck-typed, so there would be no way for it to accept anything which didn't implement `List<T>`.

Comment: I am aware about that, @supercat. Unfortunately I haven't been able to tell if the OP has those requirements or not. Seems like what is required is an iterator that is able to traverse both forward and backward, and that there should be no copies.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: IMHO, the ISP should be defined in terms of semantics rather than declaration. If `List<T>` had independent means of asking whether `add` was usable, whether `setItem` was usable, whether `remove` was usable, etc. then I would consider each such method as semantically identifying a different interface that may or may not be implemented.  Even if from a compiler standpoint lists with all different kinds of abilities were all classed as `List<T>`, I would really consider that a bunch of interfaces.  Having them unified from the compiler standpoint...

Comment: ...would make it impossible to require abilities at compile time, but on the flip side would allow wrappers and aggregates to expose the abilities of the collections encapsulated therein.  One might, for example, use the same `ObservableListWrapper` on fixed-sized lists that allow editing in place, on collections which allow items to be added but not edited afterward, and on collections that allow all kinds of modifications.  Absent such unification, it would be necessary to write a separate wrapper class for each subset of List-ish abilities.

Answer (score 10):

Note that `java.util.List` and `java.util.Set`, in addition to imposing various requirements that the compiler is capable of enforcing, also impose various requirements via Javadoc. Your class does not satisfy those requirements, and in fact it is not possible for a single class to satisfy the requirements of both interfaces.

In particular, take a look at the definitions of `equals`. For `Set`, it is:

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns `true` if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface. [[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)]

For `List`, it is:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality.  Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are *equal*.  (Two elements e1 and `e2` are *equal* if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.)  In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.  This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface. [[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)]

So, for example, `new HashSetList<Object>().equals(new HashSet<Object>())` must return `true` *and* must not return `true`.

Comment: Interesting point! Looking at `Collection.equals()` Javadoc, it states "By the same logic, it is not possible to write a class that correctly implements both the Set and List interfaces." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). In this case, I will either compromise (do I want to adhere *stronger* to the `Set` or `List` semantics?) or make sure I only compare with another `HashSetList` instance, and I will prefer the latter. Anyways, it ultimately boils down to the OP's use cases. Maybe the `equals()` method is not really required...

Comment: Good answer.  Might be helpful to the OP, though, if you explicitly list the unresolvable contradictions.

Comment: This is a good point (OP here).  However, some Collections have their own Javadoc where they disclaim other documentation.  For example, `IdentityHashMap` **"intentionally violates `Map`s general contract."**  So I feel that as long as I document my behavior, I can reasonably wave away other class's documentation.

Comment: @markspace: Nothing is ever removed from the JDK, which means that it's accrued a number of design mistakes over the years. If `IdentityHashMap<K,V>` weren't in the JDK, would you consider it to be good design? (Specifically: would you agree with its implementing `Map<K,V>` rather than something like `Map<IdentityEquivalence<K>,V>`?) If not, then -- don't be led astray by its being in the JDK.

Comment: Well, yes I consider it to be good design.  In particular, inheritance as implemented in most OO languages is well known to be insufficient to cover some real life design issues.  Strict adherence to a hierarchical system is a mistake, and flexibility is OK if its documented.  I suspect we don't agree there, but that's my opinion.

Comment: @markspace: Sorry, you have a non sequitur there: "not everything can be designed perfectly according to rigid OO principles, therefore this deviation from rigid OO principles is good design". You're missing a step. Unless you want to claim that *all* deviations from rigid OO principles are good design, you need to say *something* about this one to explain why it's good design. (I may end up agreeing with whatever opinion you have, but you haven't said what it is, so how can I know?)

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @Simon, using [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) or [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) might be a better fit if you wanted more of the `Set` semantics.

Since you said you needed the `subList()` method specifically, and if you don't mind a slight performance impact, I will suggest extending from `ArrayList` and overriding the `add()` methods to do a `contains()` check first so that you do not have two `Collection`s sitting in a custom class.

Otherwise, perhaps a secondary 'light' `Set<Integer>` storing the `hashCode()` values of the `List` elements might be enough to act as a simpified, slightly better-performing (borrowing your words, 'caveat emptor' :p) duplicate values checker.

Comment: I think you have a good idea for just using a List only, but since I do basically the same thing as a Set, it seemed appropriate to do it this way;  maybe I'm wrong.  Re. TreeSet: I think I tried a TreeSet at first and then had to use this to speed up the implementation.  IIRC O(1) instead of O(n) was a very large speed increase during insertions.

Comment: And hence my hedge 'slight performance impact'. :p

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the natural interface for a class that implements both [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) might be [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), since it would presume that there is some ordering to the elements that would support element access by index.

Essentially, the `Set` interface mandates uniqueness of elements, and the `List` interface mandates some ordering. If your implementation does not satisfy those two requirements, then it is not adhering to the contracts of the interfaces.

The other critique I have of your implementation is the duplication of elements in collections within the class. This is efficient neither in memory nor computation. The source code of ArrayList and HashSet are both available, it would be instructive to study those if performance is a concern.